# JavaEE + WildFly -> Error 404

Tags: jakarta-ee, deployment, http-status-code-404, wildfly

I'm trying to run any project from Java EE course https://github.com/javastartpl/javaee-angular - for example jax-rs-jpa project.

If I start project with WIldFly 9-11, project starts without console errors, tables are being created in MySQL but start page (http://localhost:8080/jaxrs-ejb-jpa/) show as "404 not found".

WildFly log:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/r4b2e4b56wjuxqo/Log.txt?dl=0

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: FYI: Tomcat is not a Java EE server. Use TomEE instead if you want to deploy a Java EE project to a Tomcat based server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for 'Registered web context:' in the logs to find the URL pattern you need to use.
For example, for:

```
[org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: '/sample' for server 'default-server'
```

The URL would be:

```
http://localhost:8080/sample
```

Comment: Hello, do you know how to configure that "Registered web context" for Wildfly server and Eclipse? When I deploy an Eclipse project without building the war, the log says that the project is deployed but it does not mention anything about the "Registered web context" and I have a 4040 not found error.